# Found it hard to make stacked divs responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 13em;
  
}
.animal:nth-child(n+2){
  margin-left: -5em;
}
.animal{
  width: 6em;
  height:6em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.container2{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 14em;
  height: 120px;
}

.animal1,.animal2,.animal3,.animal4,.animal5,.animal6,.animal7,.animal8{
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.animal1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}
.animal2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 3em;
}
.animal3{
  position: absolute;
  left: 6em;
}
.animal4{
  position: absolute;
  left: 9em;
}
.animal5{
  position: absolute;
  left: 12em;
}
.animal6{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15em;
}
.animal7{
  position: absolute;
  left: 18em;
}
.animal8{
  position: absolute;
  left: 21em;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Case1</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="animal">Dog</div>
      <div class="animal">Cat</div>
      <div class="animal">Mouse</div>
      <div class="animal">Duck</div>
      <div class="animal">Fish</div>
      <div class="animal">Fish</div>
      <div class="animal">Fish</div>
      <div class="animal">Fish</div>
      <div class="animal">Mouse</div>
      <div class="animal">Cat</div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <h2>Case2</h2>
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="animal1">Dog</div>
      <div class="animal2">Cat</div>
      <div class="animal3">Mouse</div>
      <div class="animal4">Duck</div>
      <div class="animal5">Fish</div>
      <div class="animal6">Fish</div>
      <div class="animal7">Fish</div>
      <div class="animal8">Fish</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are some divs that are stacked on each other. I implement the stack in two ways: (1) negative margin, and (2)position:absolute with an increment left. However, if I use negative margin, div in the second row will overflow. If I use position:absolute, when the container is small, the divs will also overflow. How can I make the stacked divs responsive? Can I make it responsive for 100 divs?

Comment: You are using fixed pixel widths. Have you tried using percentage widths, like width: 10%;? Fixed pixel widths will not be responsive. After using percentage widths, take out the negative margins.

Comment: I replaced px with em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSS-Grid solution could work for you.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 13em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2em); /* Tweak me! */
}

/* A random media query */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 26em;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 2em);
  }
}

.animal {
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="animal">Dog</div>
  <div class="animal">Cat</div>
  <div class="animal">Mouse</div>
  <div class="animal">Duck</div>
  <div class="animal">Fish</div>
  <div class="animal">Fish</div>
  <div class="animal">Fish</div>
  <div class="animal">Fish</div>
  <div class="animal">Mouse</div>
  <div class="animal">Cat</div>
</div>
```

Tweak `grid-template-columns` to your needs.

For responsiveness, simply change it across your media queries. I've demonstrated this in the example above.

Comment: Perfect answer. Do you know how to center the stacked divs? There is a little white space on the right.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. You could just adjust the width of the container to reduce the whitespace.